# how to reiterate the do-while loop when the condition is true

Tags: c++

The part i am not able to solve is - i am checking the number digits weather they are other than 1 or 0 using the checknumber(). Now, if the digits are other than 0 or 1 then ask the user to enter the num again till the digits are 0 and 1 only. After this, convert into binary and then again check the number is greater than -1 and the number is in negative then only exit. the main function:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 0, flag;
    while (num > -1) {
        do {
            cout << "Enter Number: ";
            cin >> num;
        } while (checknumber(num, flag) == 0);
        cout << "Result in Decimal = ";
        cout << binaryToDecimal(num) << endl;
    }
}
```

This is my checknumber():

```
int checknumber(int number, int flag)
{
    while (number != 0) {
        int val = number % 10;
        if ((val != 1) && (val != 0)) {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        else {
            flag = 1;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

the output i am getting when entering the number other than 0 or 1:
[image]

Comment: Your `checknumber()` function could exit without setting a return value.

Comment: You should always check the state of `cin` after reading a value.

Comment: Where is the variable `flag` initialized? I guess the issue where you never initialize `flag` in main cancels out the issue where you never use the parameter `flag` in checknumber.

Comment: @NathanPierson , I have edited now.

Comment: @tadman , i have improved the question now.

Comment: Your code prompts users to re-enter a number until `checknumber` is satisfied. So even if they enter a negative number, you still call `checknumber`. So you'll only exit the outer `while` loop if you enter a negative that also satisfies `checknumber(num) == 0`. I don't think any number actually satisfies that condition.

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question after you get an answer. Your edit makes the answer below meaningless. I reverted that edit.

Answer (score 2):

In your `checknumber` function, you're never dividing `number`, and thus you're stuck in an infinite loop. You're also returning on the first iteration of the loop. I do not understand the usage of `flag` either.

A corrected `checknumber` would be:

```
int checknumber(int number) 
{
  while(number != 0)
  {
    int val = number % 10;
    if((val != 1) && (val != 0))
    {
      return 0;
    }
    number /= 10;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: using `bool` as return type seems even more correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 I wanted to make it easier to just slot it into his existing code.